# REST service for uploading image along with other text data using slim framework

Tags: php, rest, curl, slim

i been trying to make image uploading along with other text data and to put image in one folder that have to be reference with one id field of database.

i am using Slim framework for this rest api services.
These are my codes

```
$app->post('/ProjectBook', function() use ($app) {
            verifyRequiredParams(array('flat_no', 'customer_name', 'status','photoid'));
            $response = array();
            $flat_no = $app->request->post("flat_no");
                        $customer_name = $app->request->post('customer_name');
                        $photoid = $app->request->post('photoid');
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["temp_name"], 'folders'.$photoid.'/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                        $data = array($flat_no,  $customer_name, $status, $photoid);   
            $db = getConnection();

                        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO projectbook(flat_no, customer_name, status, photoid ) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $res = $stmt->execute($data);
                            if ($res != NULL) {
                            $response["error"] = false;
                            $response["message"] = "submited successfully";

                             echoRespnse(201, $response);
                            } else {
                            $response["error"] = true;
                            $response["message"] = "Failed to insert data. Please try again";
                            echoRespnse(200, $response);
                            }  

           });
```

And i am using curl to test it

```
$curl -X POST -F "photoid=@pic.php" -F "flat_no=4&customer_name=yes&status=booked" http://localhost/Api_service/ProjectBook
```

but it doesn't work. Return my validation api of `{"error":true,"message":"Required field(s) customer_name, status, photoid is missing or empty...."}`

How can i perform this process?

Comment: Can you `print_r` the content of `$app->request->post()`?

Comment: no! it doesn't show anything about print_r. Can you please suggest me how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: I really don't understand your reply. Can you explain it? Did you try to use a function called `print_r`?